# How to find out tray system bar position in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing a cross-platform app and I wish to display a `QDialog` based on where systemtray is docked.
On windows there is just one tray but it can be docked to any side of the screen.
On Ubuntu you have top menubar and then Launcher.
Is there a way to get position of this bar (and Launcher on Ubuntu Unity) with Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a crossplatform way to get a position of the 'task bar' (e.g.
>   Launcher on Ubuntu Unity) with Qt?

Due to different platform APIs we can only rely on Qt and I would try to find the difference between the entire 'screen' geometry and 'available' one. Available geometry is basically the entire screen minus system task bar rectangle. Mind the multimonitor system and provide the widget position for getting proper entire and available monitor geometry.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html

```
QRect entireRect =
   QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry(pMyAppWidget);

QRect availRect =
   QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry(pMyAppWidget);
```

Where `availRect` should be a subset of `entireRect`. Then you need to figure out which area of `entireRect` is not inside of `availRect` and that is not complex.

Just proposing one simple way to find a 'subtracted' rectangle:

```
QRegion availRgn(availRect);
QRegion entireRgn(entireRect);
auto rects = entireRgn.subtracted(availRgn).rects();
if (rects.size() > 0) {
   // there is a task bar rectangle found
   QRect taskBarRect = rects[0];
}
```